# "Incorrect syntax" error when GRANTing permission to a username containing dots

Tags: t-sql

We are trying to grant an EXECUTE role on a stored procedure, however the following command

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_AgentIdAprCheck TO s.AgentData.Dev
```

Keeps giving us the following error (it doesn't like the first period):

```
Incorrect syntax near 's.AgentData.Dev'.
```

The user account needs to be written as we have it though. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try putting s.AgentData.Dev between square brackets ?

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_AgentIdAprCheck TO [s.AgentData.Dev]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error where the grant came after creating a view.  I needed to add **go** after the create view call

eg:

```
  CREATE VIEW Something
   (    .....
   ) ;
go
  GRANT UPDATE ON Something TO someone;
```